# 2D to 1D transformation without dimensions

Tags: math

Suppose I want to track the state of cells in a grid. Let's assume that the grid has dimensions `m x n`. I can simply create a vector of length `m*n` and track cell state using the vector. In this case, each point in the grid (which is 2D) would map to an element in the vector (1D).

One method I've used before is something like this:

```
defun 2d->1d (x, y, m, n):
    return m*y + x;

defun 1d->2d (i, m, n):
    return [i%m, i/m];
```

My problem is this:

Is there a way to have a 2D->1D mapping as above when grid dimensions are not known or when grid is infinite?

Comment: You can look at space-filling curves, e.g., [Hilbert Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) or [Z-order curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve). However, for infinite grids, it also depends on how you want to use it (really infinite or growing over time?).

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé: Growing over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are mappings from 2D to 1D for natural numbers, known as [Pairing functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function).
For example, the Cantor pairing function:

```
defun 2d->1d (x, y):
    return (1 / 2) * (x + y) * (x + y + 1) + y;
```

For the reverse function see the link above, it is a little more complex.

Comment: That's nice. Thanks